# How to use Compass to access remote Mongo instance via SSH tunnel?

Tags: mongodb, ssh, mongodb-compass

I have a Digital Ocean droplet running a NodeJS app with a Mongo DB v 3.2.21. I have been using the Compass app to access the DB via its SSH tunnel option, however it stopped working and is giving me this error when I try to connect:

connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017.

The Compass configuration is using:

Hostname: localhost

Port: 27017

Authentication: None

SSH Tunnel: Use Identity File

SSH Hostname:

SSH Tunnel Port: 22

SSH Username: root

SSH Identity File: ID_RSA

The result of netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN on the remote machine is:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      621/systemd-resolve

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      3209/sshd

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      8395/mongod

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*          LISTEN      9009/node /app/app.

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*          LISTEN      3209/sshd

tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*          LISTEN      9009/node /app/app.

Some possible clues:

The Compass app is running on a Mac that I just updated to 10.15.4 - I am not 100% sure that the problem coincided with this update but it seems suspicious.

I can SSH into the remote machine using the same credentials via Terminal on my Mac. When I SSH in, I can run the Mongo shell fine, read the db, etc.

My nodeJS app can access the DB fine.

If I stop the app, same message.
If I stop the app and also stop the mongod service, the error message is: Error creating SSH Tunnel: (SSH) Channel open failure: Connection refused

So I think the SSH tunnel is working, but Mongo is refusing the connection (?)

Any help, or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with mongodb compass. The strange thing is, when running a node.js app locally and connecting to the mongo server via ssh tunnel, there are no problems. I also tried another mongodb GUI called Database Master 10. It connects successfully with the same settings. It seems to be some kind of problem with mongodb compass itself.

Comment: Update: I tried Studio-3T and it works fine. So that would suggest the problem lies with the Compass app.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue. According to @user2876623's suggestion the problem lies with the Compass app. I just updated Compass to the latest version and it worked fine.